Why DefaultProjectionInformation.collectDescriptors() ignoring Default methods?
I wonder what is the reason of ignoring default methods when getting descriptors for DefaultProjectionInformation
I'm using spring-data-mongodb. When I try to execute a query with projection:
// Ignores fields that has default methods.
EntityProjection<T, S> projection = operations.introspectProjection(targetClass, sourceClass);


// ...

// Because of projection missing fields, we have missing field list now.
Document mappedFields = queryContext.getMappedFields(entity, projection);

// ...


I did check PR and issue but there is no information about my question.
